# DataTable Custom Search Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

Ok. I am new to DataTables and recently I needed to find a way to add my own search box for Datatables grid and failed brilliantly. I looked for a solution on Datatables.net forum and Stackoverflow but none of the solutions worked for. Although later combining two solutions and thanks to Jsfiddle I managed to find something that works and repeatable.

This just me sharing what I think is useful for a beginner like myself so it's up to you to treat it how you like.

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="column_filter form-control input-lg" id="col0_filter" size="40">

    <table class="table" id="grid1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>MotherTag</th>
                <th>Projected Delivery Date</th>
                <th>SPPO</th>
                <th>Batch Qty</th>
                <th>PO</th>
                <th>Select</th>
        </thead>
                <tr>
                <td>
                    bla bla
                </td>
                </tr>
     </table>
```

JavaScript/ Jquery

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function filterColumn ( i ) {
        $('#grid1').DataTable().column( i ).search(
            $('#col0_filter').val()
        ).draw();
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#grid1').DataTable();

        $('input.column_filter').on( 'keyup click', function () {
            filterColumn(0);
        } );
    } );
</script>
```